# How to easily manage multiple forums/web boards?

Tags: web, forum

Like many people, I follow many different web forums daily based around subjects for either my work or personal interests.

Is there any way to simplify having to logon to each one? Is there a tool that brings all of these together under one place? It can be a pain having to goto each URL, login, check recent posts etc, it would be much simpler to have it all under one place

Googles new product is supposed to bring social networking / email etc all together, does it also do the above?

Comment: 80% are either phpbb or vbulletin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some forums offer [RSS feeds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS).  If any of yours do you could subscribe to them and use something like [Google Reader](http://www.google.com/reader/) or a [desktop RSS aggregator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_feed_aggregators) to check for updates.

Comment: Add to that a good password manager and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I use RSS feeds. To read them I use FireFox's plugin "Brief". I highly recommend the tool.